# YQL weather result is null in half the time

Tags: mysql, json, yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-weather-api

Yahoo data sometimes fails to get data, "query.results is null or not an object" .

This is happening to me to on Chrome 55.0.2883.87 and fierfox 50.1.0.

This is the YQL i'm Using:

> [http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from
> weather.forecast where woeid = 2514815&format=json](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20=%202514815&format=json)

And the response:

> {"query":{"count":0,"created":"2017-01-01T22:27:51Z","lang":"en-US","results":null}}

what do i do? ideas?

Comment: Passing `diagnostics=true` as URL parameter gives us more details. Upon passing it I saw `"http-status-code":"502","http-status-message":"Cannot find server."` in the response. You should file a bug to YQL and ask them to fix this.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? We are seeing the same issue - about 30% of our calls come back null.